# getting duplicates when joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I want to join. Table1 has sales order, but it doesn’t have the name of the sales person. It only has employee ID. I have table2, that has the names of employees, and employeeID is common between the two tables. Normally I would use an inner join to get the name of the sales person from table2. The problem is that on table2, there are multiple entries for each employee. If they changed manager, or changed roles within the company, or perhaps went on FMLA, it creates a new row. Therefore, when I join the tables, it creates duplicates because of the multiple entries in table2. A sale shows 3 or 4 times in my results.

```
Select
    a.state_name
    ,order_number
   ,a.employeeID
   ,b.Sales_Rep_Name
   ,a.order_date
from
    table1 as A

 Inner join table2 as B
On a.employeeid = b.employeeID

where
   b.monthperiod = 'November'  <-- If I remove this one it adds duplicates
```

Is there a way to not get these duplicates? I tried distinct but didn’t work. Probably because the rows have at least one column different. I was able to eliminate the duplicates when I added a where clause asking for last month on table 2, but I am in a situation where I need all months, not just one. I have to manually change the month in order to get the full year.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I assume that the second table has a way to know which row is the most recent for every employee. Use that condition

Comment: If all you're after is their name... you could change table2 to.... `(Select distinct employeeID, sales_rep_name from table2) as B`  but this assumes the name's are constant.  The question becomes do you want to display the name as it was when the sale was made? :P  If so you want the min date from table2 after the order_date; making this more interesting: P  we'd need table structures for both tables to figure it out from there...

Comment: that is a good point xQbert. I am going after the sales person's name and his manager. I want to include the manager at the time the sale was made, so I will need to add the max date for table2. should I include that in the subquery?

Comment: I just realized there is no date in table 2. It shows only november 16, but the column is not a date, it is a string. I am not able to use the max option. At least I have the name now without duplicates, but cannot add the manager's name at that time of sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get list of distinct employee records  and then query the sales table

Comment: can you expand on this?